# How can I convert string height column with feet (') to numeric middle point of upper and lower ranges

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe with Growth size column. That has size range in string as 6' -7'. now i want to convert it to numeric 6 and 7. And get the middle point of them ie 6.5.

The `GSSIZE` column contains the following unique values.

```
array(\["6'-7'", nan, "5'-6'", 'Median', 'Ditch', "0'-3'", 'Open', "3'-4'",        'Boxout', "8'+", "7'-8'", "4'-5'", ' ', 'Grate', 'No Data'\],       dtype=object)

GSSIZE  DIAMETER    STATUS  TREEGUARD   GRATE_SPP
0   6'-7'    4.0            Active                 NaN
1   NaN -2.0            Active                 NaN
```

The output that I want is 6.5 for the first row. And drop all rows with non-numeric values

```
for col in ["GSSIZE"]:
df1 = df1.join(
df1[col]
.str.replace("'", "", regex=False)
.str.extract(pat=r"^[$]*(\d+)[-\s$]*(\d+)$")
.astype("float")
.rename({0: f"{col}_lower", 1: f"{col}_upper"}, axis="columns"))
```

> ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified:
> Index(['GSSIZE_lower', 'GSSIZE_upper'], dtype='object')